# Inserting multiple rows using EF6 when there is an erroneous row

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert, entity-framework-6.1

**Backgroud**
I want to insert multiple rows simultaneously using EF6.

> Code which I am using

```
using (dbContainer context = new dbContainer())
            {
                context.<DBTableName>.AddRange(List<DBTableName>);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Now let me explain how its behaving-

1. When all row are correct in format

> It works perfect and insert all rows

1. When atleast one row is having incorrect data

> 1. It throws exception but inserts other rows prior to erroneous row
> 2. It goes to catch block and forgets about all other row present after erroneous row.

**What I want**
I want the code to insert all row and should skip only rows having error.

Tried searching it on google but din't find any work around.

Comment: I think you can override the onsave event or something that you can detect a save error and recover

Comment: Hmm.. I need to workaround on this. Thanks for giving direction..